# DevExtreme Grid - Editing mode

Tags: angularjs, devextreme

tvaLst = [{
               id: 1,
               taux: 5, 
               ole: true},
    {          id: 2,
               taux: 13.01, 
               ole: false 
    }];

Imagine that from a service I retrieve the above list of Objects, and I want to show the taux value and in the second column the Edit and Delete Option Only for the lines where the attribute ole is set to true.

```
this.gridSettings = {
   bindingOptions: { dataSource: 'vm.tvaLst' },
   allowColumnResizing: true,
   scrolling: { mode: 'virtual' },
   onContentReady: this.contentReadyAction,
   paging: { enabled: false },
   editing: {
      mode: "row",
      allowUpdating: true,
      allowDeleting: true,
      allowAdding: true
}, 
columns: this.gridColumns
};
```

In editing what should I do to allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find and hide the Edit button in the [onCellPrepared](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/?version=16_1#onCellPrepared) event handler.

Here is a sample code:

```
onCellPrepared: function (options, $container) {
    if (options.column && options.column.command === "edit" && options.rowType == "data") {
        if (options.cellElement.find('a').first().text() === 'Edit') {
            if (options.data.ole === false){
              options.cellElement.find('a').first().hide();
              options.cellElement.find('a').eq(1).hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is on online example: http://plnkr.co/edit/l4PRpDkbaHRgB4ntXoQD?p=preview